# уведомления phonegap-plugin-push в фоне и уведомления android

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap, cordova, push

Имею такой код:

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: data.title,
        style: "inbox",
        icon: "res://ic_local_taxi_white_48dp",
        smallIcon: "res://ic_local_taxi_white_48dp",
        led: "FF0000" })});
```

к нему шлются такие данные:

```
$msg = [
        'body' => $message,
        'title' => $title,
        "content-available" => "1",
        'sound' => "default",
        'icon' => 'ic_local_taxi_white_48dp'
    ];
    $fields = [
        'to' => $key,
        'priority' => 5,
        'data' => $msg,
        'notification' => NULL
    ];
```

заголовок content-availble обеспечивает запуск `push.on` в фоне, однако сам андроид также показывает второе уведомление от себя.
Каким образом сделать так, чтоб android не дублировал сообщение?
Мне необходимо чтобы уведомления отображались heads-up + с кнопками, для чего использую конструктор с метода push.on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение - убрать поля title & body & message и слать данные любыми другими.
Достать их можно из `data.additionalData.name`